# Matlab cluster data into Disconnected Subsets

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, k-means

I am trying to extract a fixed (and known) number of clusters from a set of points using Matlab.
An immediate clustering method that I tried is the k-means algorithm which seems to tick all the boxes.

Unfortunately, in some cases, the subsets (or clusters) extracted are intertwined, as shown in the image below for the left-most cluster:

[[image: intertwinedClusterExample]]

Is there a way to set the k-means algorithm, so that the generated clusters are disconnected?
Is there a way to post-process the cluster indices returned by the k-means algorithm, so as to obtain "disconnected" clusters?
Alternatively, is there another clustering method that might be more suitable?

Thanks!

Comment: As of now, your question is not very clear. Is the image an output? Where do the colors come from?

Comment: Also consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that reproduces your problem